# how to half fill html form manually and send it in email body

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail, html-email, forms

I want to send html form via email and I want to fill few input fields dynamically at the time of mail composition without setting 'value' attribute programmatically every time.

I have made html form email template in Gsheet's script to send mail via gsheet and i am submitting it to the google app script web app which fetches the form data and store them into a google sheet.
here's my sheet script

```
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Send Mail").addItem("Feedback Mail", "feedbackMail").addToUi();
}

function feedbackMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var clientName = sh.getRange("A"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var senderID = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var clientID = sh.getRange("B"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var senderName = sh.getRange("C"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var service = sh.getRange("D"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var sub= sh.getRange("E"+row).getDisplayValue();
  var message = "";
  var date = new Date();

  var messageHTML = composeHtmlMsg(clientID,clientName,senderName,senderID,service,date);
  Logger.log(messageHTML);
  MailApp.sendEmail(clientID,sub,message,{'htmlBody':messageHTML});
}

function composeHtmlMsg(clientID,clientName,senderName,senderID,service,date){
  var message = "<form action= 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx67anh324kurjh_EU65BL7y9v50lPuQFnVvUvcuIwQsjYn3VRl/exec' method='GET'><input type='email' name='clientID' value='"+clientID+"'><input type='email' name='senderID' value='"+senderID+"'><input type='text' name='senderName' value='"+senderName+"'><input type='text' name='clientName' value='"+clientName+"'><input type='datetime' name='datetime' value='"+date+"'><br>"
  +"Hi "+clientName+",<br><br>"
  +"Thank you for trusting us with your "+service+" needs.we constantly strive to provide excellent services and make our clients happy.<br>"
  +"If you have a few moments, we’d love to get your feedback with a brief survey.<br>"
  +"<pre><b>Overall, how satisfied are you with our services?</b>             "
    +"Very Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response1' value='Very Happy'>   "
  +"Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response1' value='Happy'>   "
  +"Just Satisfied "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response1' value='Just Satisfied'>   "
  +"Not Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response1' value='Not Happy'><br><br>"
  +"<b>How satisfied are you with representatives?</b>                   "
  +"Very Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response2' value='Very Happy'>   "
  +"Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response2' value='Happy'>   "
  +"Just Satisfied "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response2' value='Just Satisfied'>   "
  +"Not Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response2' value='Not Happy'><br><br>"
  +"<b>How satisfied are you with the process?</b>                       "
  +"Very Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response3' value='Very Happy'>   "
  +"Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response3' value='Happy'>   "
  +"Just Satisfied "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response3' value='Just Satisfied'>   "
  +"Not Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response3' value='Not Happy'><br><br>"
  +"<b>Do you think we keep you adequately informed on all issues?</b>   "
  +"Very Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response4' value='Very Happy'>   "
  +"Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response4' value='Happy'>   "
  +"Just Satisfied "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response4' value='Just Satisfied'>   "
  +"Not Happy "
  +"<input type='radio' name='response4' value='Not Happy'><br><br>"
  +"<b>What can we improve about our services?</b><br><br>"
  +"<textarea name='message' rows='4' cols='50'></textarea><br><br></pre>"
  +"<input type='submit' value='Submit'><br><br>"
  +"</form>"
  +"Thank you for your time !<br><br>"
  return message;
}
```

Here's my web app code

```
function doGet(e) {
   var clientName = e.parameter.clientName;
   var clientID = e.parameter.clientID;
   var senderName = e.parameter.senderName;
   var senderID = e.parameter.senderID;
   var date = e.parameter.datetime;
   var response1 = e.parameter.response1;
   var response2 = e.parameter.response2;
   var response3 = e.parameter.response3;
   var response4 = e.parameter.response4;
   var response5 = e.parameter.message;

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID HiDDEN").getSheetByName("Responses").appendRow([clientName,clientID,senderName,response1,response2,response3,response4,response5,date]);

   return ContentService.createTextOutput('Thank You for your valuable feedback').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

Now i want to cutoff the usage of google spreadsheet to send mails. I want to send emails with this form integrated in gmail app(Normal mail composing procedure). Also, i want the form to insert the dynamically different values in clientID, clientName,etc. At the mail composition time for each mail sent.

But the problem is when we enter the values in form fields and send the mail. The values are lost.

Comment: Please read Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Sorry, I didnt knew that. I will remove my question

Comment: Show what you&#39;ve done / tried already, and share why it wasn't working how you wanted/envisioned

Comment: edited my question. I hope now my question is eligible